# How do I make reference to a range in another unopened workbook within a user defined function?

Tags: vba, excel, function

I have a function that doesn't work but I think should look something like this:

```
Function getdata()
    getdata = range("'\\location\on\my\computer\or\network\drive\[Data.xlsm]data'!$A$1")
End function
```

How can I get this to work so that I type "=getdata" in my workbook and it pulls through the data from the unopened workbook?

As is probably obvious, I don't want to open the source workbook to get the data, but would be ambivalent to its inclusion in the list of *linked files*.

Comment: You will have to open the workbook to retrieve the data just to be clear on that. Once open you can retrieve with a formula or vba.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need VBA to pull data from a closed workbook.

If you write in the fórmula field "=[path][filename.xlsx][sheet_name][range]"

it will pull the data from the closed workbook.

Example:

```
=C:\Users\myprofile\Desktop\[report.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

Comment: I understand that I could reference the workbook in the cell, however I want to find a way to reference it in a _FUNCTION_

Comment: In this case u can use ExecuteExcel4Macro.

Example:
getdata  = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'C:\Users\myprofile\Desktop\[report.xlsx]Sheet1'!R1C1")

This function only work with R1C1 reference.